# Getting error while connecting to restcomm server bind 0x0000000F: "System ID invalid"

Tags: restcomm

I have two different systems running restcomm smsc gw. I'm trying to configure one as a server side and other as client side. Logs for both PC are given below:

**SERVER ERROR**

10:40:32,975 INFO  [SmppServerConnector] (SmppManagement) New channel from [172.31.130.126:33712]
10:40:33,020 INFO  [UnboundSmppSession] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.172.31.130.126:33712) received PDU: (bind_transceiver: 0x0000002F 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00000001) (body: systemId [jazz] password [jazz123] systemType [] interfaceVersion [0x34] addressRange (0x00 0x00 [^[0-9a-zA-Z]*])) (opts: )
10:40:33,022 ERROR [DefaultSmppServerHandler] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.172.31.130.126:33712) Received BIND request but no ESME configured for SystemId=jazz Host=172.31.130.126 Port=33712 SmppBindType=TRANSCEIVER
10:40:33,022 WARN  [UnboundSmppSession] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.172.31.130.126:33712) Bind request rejected or failed for connection [172.31.130.126:33712] with error [SMPP processing error [0x0000000F]]
10:40:33,029 INFO  [UnboundSmppSession] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.172.31.130.126:33712) send PDU: (bind_transceiver_resp: 0x00000022 0x80000009 0x0000000F 0x00000001 result: "System ID invalid") (body: systemId [RestCommSMSC]) (opts: (sc_interface_version: 0x0210 0x0001 [34]))
10:40:33,034 INFO  [UnboundSmppSession] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.172.31.130.126:33712) Connection closed with [172.31.130.126:33712]

**CLIENT ERROR**

10:40:33,012 INFO  [DefaultSmppSession] (Thread-45) sync send PDU: (bind_transceiver: 0x0000002F 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00000001) (body: systemId [jazz] password [jazz123] systemType [] interfaceVersion [0x34] addressRange (0x00 0x00 [^[0-9a-zA-Z]*])) (opts: )
10:40:33,015 INFO  [DefaultSmppSession] (Thread-45) write bytes: [0000002f0000000900000000000000016a617a7a006a617a7a31323300003400005e5b302d39612d7a412d5a5d2a00]
10:40:33,063 INFO  [DefaultSmppSession] (jazz) read bytes: [00000022800000090000000f0000000152657374436f6d6d534d5343000210000134]
10:40:33,070 INFO  [DefaultSmppSession] (jazz) received PDU: (bind_transceiver_resp: 0x00000022 0x80000009 0x0000000F 0x00000001 result: "System ID invalid") (body: systemId [RestCommSMSC]) (opts: (sc_interface_version: 0x0210 0x0001 [34]))
10:40:33,071 ERROR [SmppSessionHandlerInterfaceImpl] (jazz) Rx : fireChannelUnexpectedlyClosed for SmppSessionImpl=client Default handling is to discard an unexpected channel closed
10:40:33,072 ERROR [SmppClientOpsThread] (Thread-45) Exception when trying to bind client SMPP connection for ESME systemId=jazz
com.cloudhopper.smpp.type.SmppBindException: Unable to bind [error: 0x0000000F "System ID invalid"]
        at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppSession.bind(DefaultSmppSession.java:341)
        at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppClient.doBind(DefaultSmppClient.java:215)
        at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppClient.bind(DefaultSmppClient.java:196)
        at org.restcomm.smpp.SmppClientOpsThread.initiateConnection(SmppClientOpsThread.java:292)
        at org.restcomm.smpp.SmppClientOpsThread.run(SmppClientOpsThread.java:129)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**Server Bind**
ESME name=server systemId=jazz state=CLOSED password=jazz123 host=127.0.0.1 port=-1 networkId=21 chargingEnabled=false bindType=TRANSCEIVER systemType=

**Client Bind**
ESME name=client systemId=jazz state=CLOSED password=jazz123 host=172.31.130.101 port=2776 networkId=21 chargingEnabled=false bindType=TRANSCEIVER systemType=

As you can see SystemID is same on both side but still im getting this error. Any help will be appreciated.